# Javascript pushing to single object

Tags: javascript

I would like to push to a single object similar to the following code

```
error = [];
error.push({name: 'Name is too short'});
error.push({email: 'Email address is too short'});
```

The problem with this is that it makes multiple objects and I wish to only create one.

Can you tell me the best way to do this or point me in the right direction, thank you.

Comment: Why are you making error an array? Couldn't you just make it an object with multiple error keys?

Comment: error.push({name: 'Name is too short', email: 'Email address is too short'}); ?

Comment: You can have multiple attributes in one object.  `{name: 'name', email: 'email' }`

Answer (score 2):

You don't `push` to an object, just make it an object and not an array and add properties:

```
var error = {};
error.name = 'Name is too short';
error.email = 'Email address is too short';
```

Answer (score 1):

Remember, your JSON syntax. You are pushing everything to an array in your example. You don't want to "push" anything here but instead append properties to an existing object:

```
var error = {};
error.name = 'Name is too short';
error.email = 'Email address is too short';
```

Comment: I assumed OP wanted to keep his array setup, but this is probably what he really wants.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add things to the object after adding it to the array:

```
error[0].email = "Email address is too short";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JQuery you can use

```
var object = $.extends({name: 'Name is too short'}, {email: 'Email address is too short'});
```

If you are not using JQuery, Ryan Lynch provide a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11197247/javascript-equivalent-of-jquerys-extend-method).