# How to extend object in gulp without installing npm

Tags: javascript, gulp, extend

How to extend object in gulp without installing npm?

```
var a = {a: 1};
var b = {b: 2};
var c = extend({}, a, b, {c:3});

c is {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
```

Comment: Using loop, copying key-value pairs from `a` and `b` to `c`?

Comment: I don't wanna write `extend` function for every gulp file

Comment: Can you clarify the question? At face this has nothing to do with gulp or npm. Are you asking how to extend an object's properties in plain Javascript? That's [very well documented](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11197343/605707).

Comment: I'm wondering if there any utility available in `gulp`, which could extend objects like `jQuery.extend` or `angular.extend` or `npm extend`. I know that the same feature could be called in grunt by `grunt.util._.merge`.

Comment: That's because grunt includes Lodash, you can also do this in your gulpfile, but you'll have to get Lodash first

Comment: So, there is no way to do `extend` in gulp without installing additional packages, right?

Answer (score 1):

Not that I know of. I would recommend that you use [object-assign](https://github.com/sindresorhus/object-assign), a forward compatible module that will delegate to the ES6 `Object.assign` if available. It's extremely lightweight at 26 lines (as of this writing).

```
var assign = require('object-assign');

var a = {a: 1};
var b = {b: 2};
var c = assign(a, b, {c:3});

console.log(c);

// => {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
```