# How can I compare two objects and reassign the second object only with the properties that are different from the first object?

Tags: javascript, object

Here my first object

```
const initialValues = {
  prenom: "anne",
  nom: "dupont",
  age: 24
}
```

Here my second object

```
const newValues = {
  prenom: "anne",
  nom: "duclos",
  age: 25
}
```

What I want is when these two objects will be compared, *newValues* will contain only property that are different from initialValues.
It'll return :

```
newValues = {
  nom: "duclos",
  age: 25
}
```

Here what I've been able to do so far:

```
const initialValues = {
  prenom: "anne",
  nom: "dupont",
  age: 24
}
const newValues = {
  prenom: "anne",
  nom: "duclos",
  age: 25
}

function keepChangedValues(object1, object2) {
    
  const keys1 = Object.keys(object1);
  const keys2 = Object.keys(object2);


  for (let key of keys1) {
    if (object1[key] === object2[key]) {
       
        //delete this propreties from newValues
    }
  }
}
keppChangedValues(initialValues, newValues)
```

Thank you for you help !

Comment: Do you mean you want to create a 3rd object that has the properties that are different between the first 2?

Comment: Not exactly. I want to keep newValues object but change his propreties. Without creating a 3rd object. I don't know if it's possible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript equivalent of jQuery's extend method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11197247/javascript-equivalent-of-jquerys-extend-method)

Comment: So you want to `delete` all properties from `newValues` that already exist with the same value in `initialValues`?

Comment: JSON.stringify(obj1) === JSON.stringify(obj2) try this

Comment: @Bergi yes exactly

Comment: @user13512145 then do just that in your loop (but name the function something else than `shallowEqual`)

Answer (score 1):

If you nkow object properties you can add this:

```
var newObject = {};
if(newValues.prenom != initialValues.prenom) newValues.prenom = newValues.prenom;
if(newValues.nom != initialValues.nom) newObject.nom = newValues.nom;
if(newValues.age != initialValues.age) newObject.age = newValues.age;
```

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution. I just need to add inside the if statement `delete object2[key]`

In this way, ONLY the propreties of the 2nd object which have the same value as the first object will be deleted from the 2nd object.