# Javascript Ellipsis and overwriting object properties

Tags: javascript, object, ellipsis

I have a function that takes in input a config file; this config file is in fact an object, something like

file `first.js`

```
// first config file

const common = require(../common)

// function that returns random day,month,year
const { day, month, year } = time.getDate()

module.exports = {
    ...common,

    dayToChoose: day,
    monthToChoose: month,
    yearToChoose: year,

    [other data]
}
```

since I can have different versions of this config file, each of them named differently (`second.js`, `third.js`, etc. with different data each), I created a "basic" configuration common to all of those files.

`common.js` is a config file that contains some data.

My question is: can `common.js` contain something like

```
const { commonDay, commonMonth, commonYear } = time.getDate()

module.exports = {
    dayToChoose: commonDay,
    monthToChoose: commonMonth,
    yearToChoose: commonYear
}
```

and put something in my `first` config file that says "if day, month, and year already exists, take those data, otherwise take the data present in the `first.js` file" ?

Something like

```
// first config file

const common = require(../common)

// function that returns random day,month,year
const { day, month, year } = time.getDate()

module.exports = {
    ...common,

    dayToChoose: dayToChoose || day,        // error: dayToChoose is not defined
    monthToChoose: monthToChoose || month,  // like above
    yearToChoose: yearToChoose || year,     // like above

    [other data which varies]
}
```

Comment: so something like `dayToChoose: common.dayToChoose || day,`

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11197247/javascript-equivalent-of-jquerys-extend-method

Comment: Thanks, but I can't use a function, I am wondering if it possible o do that inside the object

Comment: yeah @epascarello exactly, the nasty thing is that it doesn't give any error but when i use the config file it takes the last value, if both are defined :/

Comment: ok, common.DayToChoose is undefined, so is there some other way to retrieve that value?